# How to access existing code for color palettes in R

Tags: r, mapping, color-palette

I looked for a while, but I am not quite sure how to access existing color palettes in R, e.g. all the colors used for the palette `"Blues"`.

I am working on maps with the package `tmap` at the moment. There, I want to map data on on-marital births for different years to compare them. Each data set has six different values but in total I have seven in all four years to make the data comparable.

I found this page with a SAS code and used the color scale for "Blues" with seven values writing the following code for a palette:

```
library(grDevices)
blues.nmr.1984 <- colorRampPalette(c("#EFF3FF","#c6DBEF","#9ECAE1","#6BAED6","#4292C6","#2171B5"))
```

Afterwards, I was planning to use the palette for the following shapefile and in the following code:

http://www.filedropper.com/districts1994

```
library(rgdal) #for uploading shapefile
districts1994 <- readOGR(dsn ="directory", layer = "districts1994")

library(tmap)
tm_shape(districts1994) +
tm_fill("nmr", title="Non-marital ratio", palette = "blues.nmr.1984") +
tm_borders("darkgray") +
tm_format_Europe() +
tm_legend(text.size=.8,
            title.size=1.1,
            position = c("right","bottom"),
            height=1,
            width=1) + 
 tm_layout("1994", title.position=c("left", "top"),
            inner.margins=c(0.02,0,.02,0.15), asp=1)
```

Apparently, not all of the colors are know, because I got the following error when using it: `Error in col2rgb(col) : invalid color name 'blues.nmr.1984'`
So, I thought knowing the original R code for the colors in the `"Blues"` palette would be better.

If I missed any post I would still be thankful if you can recomment an existing one.

Comment: `blues.nmr.1984` will be a function, not a list or vector of colors. You would need to call it with an argument. The small amount of code works fine on my machine. What was the code that threw that error?

Comment: afterwards I used it for this code as a palette whereas before I used `"Blues"`: `tm_shape(districts1994) +
  tm_fill("nmr", title="Non-marital ratio", palette = "blues.nmr.1994") +
  tm_borders("darkgray") +
  tm_shape (states) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_format_Europe() +
  tm_legend(text.size=.8,
            title.size=1.1,
            position = c("right","bottom"),
            height=1,
            width=1) + 
  tm_layout("1994", title.position=c("left", "top"),
            inner.margins=c(0.02,0,.02,0.15), asp=1)`

Comment: if anyone wants to try if out, I can send the two shape files

Comment: No mechanism for sending files. Post them in an accessible location and post a link .... and the code as an edit to the question body!

Comment: Thanks, edited the post now.

Comment: Now the error I get is "Error in as.list.environment(environment()) : object 'states' not found" and the string "states" is not among the names of list elements in `districts1994`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the palette function with an argument it will return color values:

```
palette = blues.nmr.1984(5))
```

More specifically in this instance (trimming the extra stuff that used undefined objects):

```
library(rgdal) 
directory <- path.expand("~/Downloads/districts1994") # tilde expansion not supported apparently
districts1994 <- readOGR(dsn =directory, layer = "districts1994")

library(tmap)
 png(); tm_shape(districts1994) +
 tm_fill("nmr", title="Non-marital ratio", palette = blues.nmr.1984(5)) +
 tm_borders("darkgray"); dev.off()
```

[image]